# Verification and hint for my answers to a basic statistics table

Tags: statistics

Sorry if this question seems very basic. I tried to find the answer by goolging. But because I do not know the correct keyword cannot find anything. This is a basic statistics problem. I attempted questions but I need them to get **verified**. I also do not know the answer of question 5.

The following table was drawn up to show the results of a quiz:
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
\text{x} & \text{f} & \text{fx} & \text{c.f.} \\
\hline
5 & 8 &  & \\
6 & 12 &  & \\
7 & 15 &  & \\
8 & 17 &  & \\
9 & 9 &  & \\
\end{array}
$$

1. Complete the $f \times x$ column.
2. Complete the cumulative frequency column.
3. Calculate the mean correct to one decimal place.
4. What is the mode?
5. What is the Median?

**My answers:**
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
\text{x} & \text{f} & \text{fx} & \text{c.f.} \\
\hline
5 & 8 & 40 & 40 \\
6 & 12 & 72 & 112 \\
7 & 15 & 105 & 217 \\
8 & 17 & 136 & 353 \\
9 & 9 & 81 & 434 \\
\end{array}
$$

**Answer of Q3.** $(40 + 72 + 105 + 136 + 81) \div 5 = 86.8$

**Answer of Q4.** Mode is 8 because it has frequency of 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Q3: You should divide by the sum of the frequencies and not by $5$.

Answer to Q5: Identify the $x$ value where the cumulative **percentage** crosses 50%. In other words, at what $x$ value do the cumulative number of observations equal 50% of total observations?

Comment: In regard to Q3, the count of frequencies is 5 and the sum is (40 + 72 + 105 + 136 + 81). If I divide by sum I will get 0/0 which is undefined.

Comment: 50% of commutative frequencies is (434 - 40) / 2 = 197. 197 is somewhere between 6 and 7. How can I know the exact number?

Comment: By the way do you know what this table is called? I want to read more information about this, but I do not know the keyword to search. Thanks

Comment: I you mean you should do $(40+72+105+136+84)/(8+12+15+17+9)$. To convince yourself why this should be consider a simpler problem where the data looks like so: ${1, 3, 2, 2, 2}$ What is the mean?

Comment: You could search for 'histogram', 'frequency', 'cumulative frequency', 'weighted mean' and so on.